# Accessing state of children from parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I don't think I fully understand how the Parent/Child relationship works in React. I have two components, `Column` and `Space`. When a `Column` is rendered, it creates some `Spaces`. I thought that meant that the `Column` would be the parent to those `Spaces`, but either I'm wrong or I'm using some part of `React.Children.count(this.props.children)` incorrectly - it always tells me that any given `Column` has 0 children.

Simplified models:

```
var Column = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {childCount: '', magicNumber: this.props.magicNumber};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var newCount = React.Children.count(this.props.children);
        this.setState({childCount: newCount});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='Column'>
               {
                   Array.from({ length: this.state.magicNumber }, (x,y) => <Space key={y}/>)
               }  
            </div>

        );
    }
});

var Space = React.createClass({ 
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="Space">
              space here
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

It seems like no matter where I put `React.children.count(this.props.children)` in a `Column`, it tells me there are 0 children. I would expect the `Column` generated in the example code to have five children, since five `Space`s are created within it.

I figured maybe I was trying to count the Children before they were fully loaded, so I tried writing a click handler like this:

```
//in Column
setChildCount: function () {
    var newCount = React.Children.count(this.props.children);
    this.setState({childCount: newCount});
}
```

Then adding a button like this in my `Column`:

```
...
render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='Column'>
               {
                   Array.from({ length: this.state.magicNumber }, (x,y) => <Space key={y}/>)
               }  
            <button onClick={this.setChildCount} />
            {this.state.childCount}
            </div>
        );
```

But my `childCount` is always and forever 0. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Ultimately, I want to get a count of all children elements who have X attribute in their state set to Y value, but I am clearly a step or three away from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Column component doesn't have any children on that code. Childrens are components which are wrapped by the parent component. So imagine:

```
<Column>
 <Space/>
 <Space/>
<Column/>
```

In this case the parent `Column` has two children `Space`

On your code:

```
        <div className='Column'>
           {
               Array.from({ length: this.state.magicNumber }, (x,y) => <Space key={y}/>)
           }  
        </div>
```

You are creating new components inside a `div`not inside the component `Column`

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is it possible for a component to `render` its own children like I'm trying to do here, or can that sort of thing only work properly in `ReactDOM.render`? Sorry if this is too much of a deviation from the OP.

Comment: Read the logic of parent child terminology on the react tutorial ;) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `Space` components as part of the `Column` component. The parent/child relationship captured by `this.props.children` looks like this:

```
var Column = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <div className="column">
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Column>
    <Space /> //little space children
    <Space />
  </Column>
);
```

To get at your specific problem, you don't *need* anything like `this.props.children` because you have everything right there in your render method.

So the answer to your question is: apply the same logic as when you render them.